# Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, show that $|g \circ H| = |H|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. A relation on $G$ is defined:

$g \equiv g_1$ if and only if $g^{-1} \circ g_1 \in H$.

I have already shown that this is indeed an equivalence relation and that the equivalence classes are the left cosets $g \circ H$ of $H$ in $G$. From this I have to show that $|g \circ H| = |H|$.

I know from Lagrange's theorem that, $|g \circ H| =|G:H| = \frac{|G|}{|H|}$. I'm having trouble proceeding from here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Give a bijection from $H$ to $gH$. What is a natural mapping which takes an element $h\in H$ to an element of $gH=\{gh:h\in H\}$?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be a one to one mapping? $f(h) = gh$ for instance? Then that would mean that $H$ and $gH$ have the same cardinality?@MikeEarnest

Comment: You are correct. All you have to do is prove that $f$ is one to one and onto; this then implies that $H$ and $gH$ have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 4):

Your relation is false: from *Lagrange's theorem*, you have 
$$\lvert G\rvert =[G:H]\cdot\lvert H\rvert. $$

More simply the map $\;\begin{aligned}[t]H&\rightarrow gH\\
h&\mapsto gh\end{aligned}\;$ is bijective.

Comment: Does this mean that since, there is a bijective mapping, the order of $|H| = |gH|$?

Comment: Absolutely. $ $